# Positions Footer at very bottom with only absolute content

Tags: html, css, footer, positioning, absolute

Right now I create a page with more or less only fixed and absolute content. The first viewport was pretty easy to create because it has a max height of 100vh. So I styled the second section with margin-top: 100vh. For now everything works. But the second section isn't 100vh height anymore. The height is more or less unknown.

Now I want to create a new section or a footer. But the problem is that it's stuck to the top of the page. Like there is no other content. I think this is because of position: absolute on every other element.
Also position: absolute and bottom: 0 doesnt work for the footer. Then its just stuck to the bottom of the viewport but not of the whole page.

How can I style my next stuff to keep it below the other content?

The reason why I use position: absolute is for a fixed background, created with css.
Maybe there is a smarter way to have content overlapping the background without position absolute?

I think thats the relevant code you need for my problem:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;}
.first {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 110vh;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: coral;
  z-index: 200;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100vw;
}


.background {
  background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px;
  background-color: #12364a;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  }
  .background:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0%, rgba(7, 9, 11, 0.56) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    Lorem ipsum first page
</div>

<div class="second">
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
    <p>Some Images here</p>
</div>

<footer>
    this is the footer
</footer>


<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets to your question.

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 1):

wrap all your content in a div that you position: absolute instead of having all elements absolute.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;}
.first {
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 110vh;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
}

footer {
  background-color: coral;
  z-index: 200;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100vw;
}


.background {
  background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px;
  background-color: #12364a;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  }
  .background:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0%, rgba(7, 9, 11, 0.56) 100%);
}

.test{
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="test">
 
  <div class="first">
  Lorem ipsum first page
  </div>

  <div class="second">
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
   <p>Some Images here</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
   this is the footer
  </footer>
 </div>

 <div class="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you adding so much css and making it difficult ! What I understood from the question can be done with simple css. here is an example:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px;
  background-color: #12364a;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  Lorem ipsum first page
</div>
<div class="second">
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
</div>
<footer>
  this is the footer
</footer>
<div class="background"></div>
```

if you want 100vh spacing between .first and .second then:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px;
  background-color: #12364a;
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}

.first {
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}

footer {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  Lorem ipsum first page
</div>
<div class="second">
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
  <p>Some Images here</p>
</div>
<footer>
  this is the footer
</footer>
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: this is pretty neat !